# растет число G-SENSOR shock counter для нового HDD Seagate ST10000NM0086

Tags: железо, hdd, smart

Есть новый Seagate ST10000NM0086 на 10ТБ.

Воткнул его в домашний системный блок. Очень шумный, головка бегает туда-сюда, и словно молоточек по корпусу системника бьёт.

Посадил его на самоклеющийся уплотнитель дверей и положил в свободную полочку системника. Стало очень тихо в квартире.

Наблюдаю показатели SMART в Victoria HDD. Растет число  G-SENSOR shock counter. При этом два других жестких диска имеют значение 0 (на протяжении уже 5 лет работы).

Трогаю его во время работы, а он "пинается". Закрепил его обратно жестко на болтики как положено. Наблюдаю...

Показатель G-SENSOR shock counter продолжает расти. Сейчас его значение 116.

Как думаете это нормальная ситуация? Может что посоветуете?

P.S. Это серверный вариант ЖД. Выбрал именно эту модель, так как понравились показатели живучести согласно статистики BACKBLAZE: https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-stats-for-2018/

[image: https://b.radikal.ru/b21/1905/f3/fa868611973c.jpg]